# How to count 'red' from 'redish' in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, split, list-comprehension

I have a bit of a tricky question - I want to count only words that say 'red' and avoid those which have red in their name, but are not just 'red'. For example I would want to avoid counting 'redish', 'darkred' etc. I have my code below but I'm not having a whole lot of luck. The input would be for example: 'red', 'redish', 'darkred'

I know my code is only looking for 'red' so I guess my question is how do I use the split function to only pull out 'red' and avoid everything else?

```
cars = input("Cars: ") #'redish, darkred, sortofred, red'
cars_red = cars.split('red') #I only want to count the one 'red'
print('red:', cars_red.count(cars_red))
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
cars = input("Cars: ") 
cars_red = cars.split(', ') 
count = 0
for word in cars_red:
    if word == 'red':
        count += 1
print('red:',count)
```

**Input:**

```
redish, darkred, sortofred, red
```

**Output:**

```
red: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that split() is used to "split" a string according to a delimiter.  It may be used to create the list of colors.  Then you need to think about how to count all that match exactly 'red'.

One method is to count using the reduce() function:

```
# parse input into cars list
cars = input("Cars: ").split(', ')

# Prepend initial count of 0 and accumulate by matching 'red'
cars.insert(0, 0)
count = reduce(lambda count, color: count + (color == 'red'), cars)

print 'red: ' + str(count)
```

The same may be done in many ways including usage of a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

To have a filtered list just with cars of specific colors, and thus counting them, you can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function that allows to have a very concise code.
Supposing that you are using a CSV format, possibly with some spaces (as in your input example) to trim using `strip`, a possible solution with the `main` would look like:

```
def filter_cars_by_color(cars, color):
    return list(filter(lambda car: car == color, [car.strip() for car in cars.split(',')]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cars = input("Cars: ")
    color = input("Color to search:")
    cars_red =  filter_cars_by_color(cars, color)
    print('Number of cars exactly %s: %d' % (color, len(cars_red)))
```

Note that, in the answer, I am referring to python 3.x, as, even if not marked, it seems that the OP is using python 3.x. If python 2.7 is used, then, instead of `input`, [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) should be used, as otherwise the input would be processed as python expression.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
var valueToLookup = "red";

var count = cars.filter(function(v) { return v === valueToLookup; }).length;
```

Comment: Based on the content of the question, please answer in Python (hint, python also has filter)